# Concatenating txt files in date file order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of files in a directory that I want concatenated into one file.

The files are in date order, e.g XXYYYYMMDD_hhmmss.txt. I want to read all the files, and insert the files in date order. If for example I do 1 months worth to combine but one of the files has not been processed, I want to leave a space for it in the merged txt file for it to be inserted and filled so that it is all chronological..

I can merge the files no problem:

```
with open('MergedFiles.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
     for files in filePath:
          with open(files, 'rb') as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
```

And I know I would need to turn the file names into datetime objects at some point so that I know where to insert the data, but I really don't know where to start about implementing this.

Any steering in the right direction appreciated! I might be going about this the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Is `XX` just an additional serialized number prepended to the date? What is `filePath`? and how is that ordered? What is your question exactly? Your code looks OK other than what I asked.

Comment: Yes XX is just a serialized number and has no relation to the date. filePath is the directory list where the txt files are stored and yes it is in date order. What I want is instead of just appended data to the end of the file, I want to be able to 'place' txt data in a specific order in the merged file. If a file with a date is missing, but I merged the file already, then that missing file is now avilable, I don't just want to append it to the end. I want it placed in a specific line. Hope that helps.

Comment: are all the files of uniform number of lines, so that you can calculate an insert point?  can you insert a commented line in your merged file to say where one text file starts or ends?

Comment: The number of lines in each file is not uniform.

Comment: Reading the deleted question -- that is the right approach. You cannot 'leave room' for a file yet to come at the OS level since there is no 'insert' into a straight text file. You can either come up with your own new file index method (something that a word processor might do) or you are forced to read the file up to the point of insertion, insert, then append the rest of the file. In essence rewrite the file entirely. There is no shortcut to this for a straight unindexed text file. None. There are *logical* shortcuts, like using `mmap` but you still end up rewriting the entire file.